# Implement a class for representing a linestring and implement a method length() that returns the sum of the length of (any number) or segments

Tags: python, gis

I implemented a class to define a LineString(object). The LineString takes in any number of points representing different line segments. I need to calculate the length of each line segment and add them all together to get the total length of the line string. I cannot see where my code went wrong because I am not able to pass the asserts to test if my length function works.

I have tried to create a variable instead of a list to sum the length of each line segment but it still does not work.

```
from math import sqrt

class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, i, j):
        self.x = self.x + i
        self.y = self.y + j

class LineString(object):
    def __init__(self, *coordinates):
        self.coords = [Point(*p) for p in coordinates]
        self.lengths = []

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if type(key) == tuple:
            return self.coords[key[0]][key[1]]
        else:
            return self.coords[key]

    def move(self, delta_x, delta_y):
        for self in self.coords:
            self.move(delta_x, delta_y)

    def length(self):
        # base formula: length = sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
        points_temp = self.coords
        for i in range(len(points_temp) - 1):
            length = sqrt(((self.coords[i + 1].x - self.coords[i].x) ** 2) + (
                    (self.coords[i + 1].y - self.coords[i].y) ** 2))
            self.lengths.append(length)
        return sum(self.lengths)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Tests for LineString
    # ===================================
    lin1 = LineString((1, 1), (0, 2))  # lin1 is an instance of LineString

    assert lin1.length() == sqrt(2.0)

    lin1.move(-1, -1)  # Move by -1 and -1 for x and y respectively

    print(lin1)

    assert lin1[0].y == 0  # Inspect the y value of the start point.
    # Implement this by overloading __getitem__(self, key) in your class.

    lin2 = LineString((1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2))

    assert lin2.length() == 2.0

    lin2.move(-1, -1)  # Move by -1 and -1 for x and y respectively

    assert lin2.length() == 2.0

    assert lin2[-1].x == 1  # Inspect the x value of the end point.

    print('Success! Line tests passed!')
```

I keep getting an error with the second to last assert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recommend using Python's unit test framework,
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html

That way, instead of just saying "getting an error with the second to last assert" - you'll use `self.assertEqual(lin2.length(), 2.0)` and it will print not just that something is wrong, but also actual value of `lin2.length()`.

Second, you should never compare double values for equality - they are not precise and tiny errors might cause calculations to be just a bit off to cause equality to fail. Use assertAlmostEqual instead - https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual

But that was not the problem here. The simplest way to find the error is to use Python interactively. Just run in interactive shell:

```
lin2 = LineString((1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2))
lin2.length()
2.0
lin2.length()
4.0
```

Here is the problem - the length() function does not clear `self.lengths` field and it keeps growing with every computation!